# Example of not normal subgroup $N$ such that not all orbits of $X$ under $N$ have the same length

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a finite group that works transitively on $X$, what is a simple example of a subgroup $N$ that is not normal such that not all orbits of $X$ under $N$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: $\langle (1,2) \rangle < S_3$.

Comment: what is the group, subgroup, X, orbits in this case?

Comment: @Stan: The group $G$ is $S_3$ the group of permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$. The subgroup $N$ is the subgroup generated by the permutation $(1,2)$ that interchanges $1$ and $2$ while leaving $3$ fixed; its other member is the identity permutation. The set $X$ is $\{1,2,3\}$. The orbits of $X$ under $N$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3\}$. Since the permutations $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$ don’t commute, it’s easy to see that $N$ is not normal in $G$.